# I can't find the problem with this i never made a javascript discord bot before?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I never made a javascript discord bot and I wanted to make one, so i found a recent good looking tutorial to learn the bascics, but I can't make it work.?

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
require("dotenv").config();

import { Client, 
         GatewayIntentBits, 
         ButtonBuilder, 
         ButtonStyle, 
         ModalBuilder, 
         TextInputBuilder, 
         TextInputStyle } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
    ],
});



client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I ran these commands before:

```
touch index.js
npm install discord.js
npm i dotenv
touch .env
```

then i put this in the .env file:
`TOKEN = "discord bot token"`

ERROR:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: it gives an error

Comment: If you want to use ES import syntax you need to add `"type": "module"` to your*package.json*. Otherwise use `require()` you should stick to only using one form

Answer (score 1):

At Javascript:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

More info at library [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: i tried it without the dotenv
i made a const TOKEN = "token"

nad put that in the login but still wont work there is a problem with the import or something

Answer (score 0):

Completing @paulo-eduardo's answer, if you want to use import and export, you need to either use a bundler, or a node version that supports this syntax.

Here, you are mixing require and import/export syntaxes.

Given the error you have, you should only use the `require` syntax.

Meaning, the final code should result in:

```js
require("dotenv").config();

const { Client, 
         GatewayIntentBits, 
         ButtonBuilder, 
         ButtonStyle, 
         ModalBuilder, 
         TextInputBuilder, 
         TextInputStyle } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
    ],
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: This is a toally different error, and my answer unblocked you. Please visit [Discord.js Discord server](https://discord.gg/djs) for further help.